# ajax get, alternate url if original not found

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, get

I'm wondering if it is possible to provide an alternate url if original file is not found.
To be specific:

The link to the file is dynamically generated, the last four characters are the current year. There isn't always a file for the current year so my goal is to offer a backup url with the previous year in it's place.

Here is an example of the current code I'm working with:

```
var newXML = function(url) { 
    var newDoc = null; 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: url, 
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false, 
        success: function(xml) { 
            newDoc = $(xml); 
        }, 
        error: function(jqXHR, text, errorMsg) { 
            alert("The following error occurred: "+ errorMsg);  
        } 
    }); 
    return newDoc; 
}
```

Whenever I need to retrieve a doc I just invoke newXML passing it a url ending in the current year. How do I offer a backup it that file doesn't exist?

Comment: Call the function again with another URL if the ajax call fails, and you should be using `done()` and `fail()` for that, and you should create your logic so that it works with asynchronous calls.

Comment: @adeneo I agree, maybe even set a variable as the URL and if you get error, set the variable to the new URL possibly with a setTimeout to retry the old URL if need be. Interesting Question.

Comment: I think you should change your function into recursive function by using `fail()`.

Comment: @adeneo,@Zach,@Phong, thank you for your input. I've started studying the approaches you've mentioned and in doing so it looks like I'm using an outdated method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty fix. I added this code after my first attempt at locating my primary file.

```
setTimeout(function(){
 if($('#latest').is(':empty')){ "Added code here requesting an alternate file if div is empty" }}, 1000);
```

I'm only using this until I get up to speed on a proper approach outlined in the comments above. Specifically [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

I don't advocate using this approach unless you're under deadline and are putting out other fires. Once those fires are put out I'll take a few hours to understand how to properly fix this. That said, it is working fine.